# What to do with Cognito access token?

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, asp.net-core, access-token, amazon-cognito

So I'm developing a .NET Core MVC application for internal use in the company. I've just implemented user accounts with AWS Cognito and the [Cognito .NET identity provider](https://github.com/aws/aws-aspnet-cognito-identity-provider)

I also have an API which the MVC app is interacting with. I want to use the same User Pool to secure this API so the user just logs in to the MVC app and they can then use both the app and not have to worry about access to the API which happens in the background.

I have a mixture of calls both from the server side of the app as well as from JavaScript.

[image]

I know how to get an access token from the server side of my application but I'm am unsure of what I should actually be doing with it once I've got it. I'd like whatever access token I get on the server side to also be available on the client side. This is because to get a new access token from JavaScript involves re-inputting the username and password (see step 5 here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/tutorial-integrating-user-pools-javascript.html).

My initial thought was to request an access token when the user logs in (server side) and store it in a cookie. I have read that you should always enable `HttpOnly` and `Secure` when storing sensitive information in cookies though. This means that JavaScript cannot access the cookies which in turn prevents XSS attacks. Sadly, this means that I'd be unable to retrieve the access token when I need to make calls to my API from the client side of my application. I believe the token may even be too large to store in a cookie anyway?

I also know that sensitive information should most certainly [not be stored in local storage](https://medium.com/@saivicky2015/why-jwt-shouldnt-be-stored-in-local-storage-aa9aeacc46a0) so that's not an option.

This is my first time dealing with the world of access tokens so apologies if this is a duplicate.